# XSLT transformation: flattening nested node based on its attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to flatten XML file using XSLT. Example (there could be any number of `node` and `edge` nodes):

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns">
  <graph>

    <node id="0">
      <data key="label">A</data>
      <data key="tag1">0</data>
      <data key="tag2">0</data>
    </node>

    <edge id="0" source="0" target="1">
      <data key="label">REFERENCED_TO</data>
    </edge>

  </graph>
</graphml>
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns">
  <graph>

    <node id="0" label="A">          
      <data key="tag1">0</data>
      <data key="tag2">0</data>
    </node>

    <edge id="0" source="1" target="0" label="REFERENCED_TO"/>

  </graph>
</graphml>
```

How can I flatten only those `data` tags that have `key` attribute set to `"label"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I flatten only those data tags that have key attribute set to
>   "label"?

How about:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:gml="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- add label attribute -->
<xsl:template match="gml:node | gml:edge">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="gml:data[@key='label']">
            <xsl:attribute name="label"><xsl:value-of select="gml:data[@key='label']"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- suppress label element -->
<xsl:template match="gml:data[@key='label']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Quite amazing, I wrote exactly the same answer (only minor diffs) but you already added yours. Just deleted mine - no point in having two of the same.

Comment: I think this can be considerably simplified; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Having some spare time i came up with the following XSLT (it's 1.0 based so pretty verbose)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
                xmlns:g="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[*/@key='label']">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="label">
        <xsl:value-of select="*[@key='label']/text()" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(@key='label')]"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

The solution from hor257k seems to contain three tests for @key='label' where one would do. Here's an attempt to improve it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:gml="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- convert label element to attribute -->
<xsl:template match="gml:data[@key='label']">
  <xsl:attribute name="label">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and for completeness, here's the XSLT 3.0 version:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:gml="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<!-- convert label element to attribute -->
<xsl:template match="gml:data[@key='label']">
  <xsl:attribute name="label" select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am afraid your improved XSLT 1.0 version will work **only** if `<data key="label">` is ALWAYS the **first** child of its parent. Otherwise you will get an error like "An attribute node (label) cannot be created after the children of the containing element". I did not want to make such assumption - and if I had, I would have stated so clearly.